# Sinatra Multiple Parallel Requests Variable Behaviour

Tags: ruby, variables, sinatra, instance-variables

I am fairly new to ruby and would like to understand how class instance variables behave in case of multiple parallel requests.

I have a method inside my controller class which is called everytime for each request for a specific operation (create in this case)

```
class DeployProvision
    def self.create(data)
        raise "Input JSON not received." unless data
        # $logger.info input_data.inspect
        failure = false
        response_result = ""
        response_status = "200"
        @validator = SchemaValidate.new
        validation = @validator.validate_create_workflow(data.to_json)
    end
end
```

This method is called as (DeployProvision.create(data))

I am a little confused on how @validator class instance variable behaves when multiple requests come. Is it shared among multiple requests. Is it a good idea to declare this as class instance variable instead of a local variable ?

I am working on an existing code base and would like to understand the intent of creating @validator as a class instance variable instead of local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can write ultra-simple script like this:

```
require 'sinatra'
class Foo
  def self.bar
    @test = Time.now
    puts @test
  end
end

get '/' do
  Foo.bar
end
```

and you'll see it does nothing, because with every call, you're creating new instance of Time(SchemaValidate in your code).

If you used memoization and had something like `@validator ||= SchemaValidate.new` you would have one instance of SchemaValidate stored between requests.

I don't think that'd change anything in terms of performance and I don't have idea why would anyone do something like that.

You can have some fun with ultra-simple scripts with sinatra to test how it behaves.

Good luck with this code!

Comment: I understand that everytime we are creating a new instance of Time, so the address in memory will be new. My question is say after the first incoming request the address to which test points is a1 and after second incoming request it is a2. If somewhere down in the code for the first request shouldnt test point to a2 (as modified by second request) instead of a1 as the class instance varibale gets shared among every instance of class.